# Alternate Causes for "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.'"

Tags: core-data

thanks for reading. We've recieved crash reports on our iOS app with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

This occurs when our main queue NSManagedObjectContext attempts to save:

```
BOOL saved = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Which occurs in a block submitted via:

```
[managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:saveBlock];
```

The internet (especially SO) is full of explanations for this error suggesting that we never had a persistent store cooridinater (that we failed to create it properly when we built the core data stack).  However, it's difficult to see how we could get to this point in program execution without a persistent store coordinator.  For kicks, i commented out the line where we set the persistent store and the app crashes almost immediately (without getting to our save method).

Does anyone know if there's an alternate cause for this exception or is it ALWAYS because there is no persistent store?  Is there any way to lose a persistent store?

A little more color: we use parent/child NSManagedObjectContexts in order to load data in a background thread.  The full save method looks like this:

```
-(void)saveWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext successHandler:(void (^)())successHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext, NSError*))failureHandler
{
    void(^saveBlock)() = ^() {
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error saving %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            failureHandler(managedObjectContext, error);
        } else {
            if (managedObjectContext.parentContext != nil) {
                [self saveWithManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext.parentContext successHandler:successHandler failureHandler:failureHandler];
            } else {
                successHandler();
            }
        }
    };

    BOOL isMainContext = managedObjectContext.parentContext == nil;

    if (isMainContext) {
        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:saveBlock];
    } else {
        [managedObjectContext performBlock:saveBlock];
    }
}
```

It can be called from a background thread which will call save: on the NSManagedObjectContext via a performBlock: and then rescursively call this method on the parent NSManagedObjectContext in order to save it.  When the app crashes, it's always on the main thread which makes sense because the main queue context is the only one that needs a persistent store.

Many thanks for any help. I did cross post to devforums.apple.com, so my apologies if you've seen this twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corresponded offline with [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington) who made the innocuous comment: "Persistent stores shouldn't go away unless you remove them (and I'm assuming you don't do that)." 'course i DO do that when i tear down the core data stack (when a user logs out.)  When i tear down the stack, i call reset on my root managed object context (the only one i have a reference to) and then remove the persistent store.  However, if there are pending changes in a child context, they'll propagate up to my now persistentstoreless root context causing the crash on save.  Since there's a good reason why parent contexts don't keep track of their children, i don't want to keep track of them either.  Instead i just confirm that there is either a parent context or a persistent store coordinator (with at least one store) before calling save.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two places to look.

First, check what happens when you first add the persistent store to the Core Data stack. That would be in the app delegate if you are using the Apple template, but typically somewhere in your code when the app is initialized there is a call to

`addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.

Second, as you mention background threads and because you are passing a managed object context to your method, you possibly have child contexts. Check that you have properly assigned either a valid parent context or the store coordinator to the child context when you create it.

Comment: Thanks Mundi.  The core data stack builds just fine (the app crashes almost immediately if i explicitly set the persistent store to nil when building the stack).  For my background contexts, those always get their parentContext set immediately on instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

This error is unfortunately ambiguous.  I have seen it when using configurations and there is a typo in the configuration name or in one case where a configuration name was passed in when there were no configurations in the model.

So my first line of testing would be to look at your Core Data stack creation code.  Can you add that to your question so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I know that my stack builds correctly since the app crashes almost immediately if i explicitly set the persistent store to nil when building the stack.

Comment: Setting the configuration wrong is not the same as setting it to nil.  The configuration typo will show up later, not immediately.

Comment: I hear you on that ("Setting the configuration wrong is not the same as setting it to nil"), it was just a quick way for me to see what would happen if i bungled the stack setup.